# Injecting Pydantic Request models into an imported FastAPI Router?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm looking to define an internal package that contains a few base FastAPI Routers. They have endpoint logic defined. The endpoint's code logic is mostly agnostic to the form of the data as it is pipelined away.

However, I want to import those routers in different apps where the Pydantic model will change slightly between them. In each case I want FastAPI to validate the requests body to the specific app's own pydantic model. But I want to use the base routers & endpoint logic.

Is there a way of writing an APIRouter, writing the endpoints, but allowing another file to import the router and inject/configure the expected pydantic request model for each endpoint?

Edit: I'm 90% certain this can be done with the FastAPI Dependencies but I can't work out how, despite being an in-theory simple case.

Comment: Could you please share some code, it sounds possible, but it's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do.